# AndroidTV Home Screen channels - progressbar

Tags: progress-bar, android-tv, homescreen

I'm attempting to show a progressbar of my programs in my custom channel on Android TV home screen, but can't get it displayed

Here is what I tried so far (`channel` and `program` are my custom models)

```
PreviewProgram.Builder()
     .setType(TvContractCompat.PreviewProgramColumns.TYPE_CLIP)
     .setChannelId(channelId)
     .setTitle(program.title)
     .setPosterArtUri(program.backdrop?.let { Uri.parse(it) })
     .setDescription(program.description)
     .setLongDescription(program.description)
     .setStartTimeUtcMillis(program.startTime.millis)
     .setEndTimeUtcMillis(program.endTime.millis)
     .setDurationMillis(program.durationObj.millis.toInt())
     .setLastPlaybackPositionMillis(program.positionMs?.toInt() ?: 0)
     .setLogoUri(channel.whiteLogoUrl?.let { Uri.parse(it) })
     .setAuthor(channel.title)
     .build()
```

I would expect it would either compute progress from `startTimeUtcMillis` / `endTimeUtcMillis` compared to current system time .. or by fraction of `lastPlaybackPositionMillis` and `DurationMillis`.

Any idea how to show the progressbar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.
Progress bar is displayed when you add content to the "Watch Next" channel to suggest the user to continue watching where they left off or suggest a new episode.

Home screen channels are just for adding recommended content for your app and hence will NOT show progress bar.

Read more details here:
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-channel